# How to cancel the camera jitter from a video using MATLAB?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, matlab

I have a video which has some noise because of camera jitter. How to cancel the effect due to camera jitter using MATLAB?

Answer (score 0):

Since this question has sat unanswered for a while, I'll take a stab at it. I can't provide a MATLAB specific solution, but I can provide a general one.

Assuming you mean slight frame-to-frame variation in camera position when you write "jitter", this can be handled using sparse optical flow methods.

1. First, compute the pixel-wise change between frames 1 and 2.  I've used the Lucas-Kanade method - [here](http://server.cs.ucf.edu/~vision/source.html) is a link to some MATLAB source code.  Note that this method is pretty fast since it applied to feature sets (i.e. corners, etc.).
2. At this point, you now know the shift (measured in pixels) between frame 1 and 2.  To register the two images, simply shift frame 2 "back" by the specified shift values.  For example, if the difference between frame 1 and frame 2 was (-3,1) - meaning three pixels to the left and one pixel down - you can simply translate frame 2 three pixels to the right and one pixel up.
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 for all subsequent adjacent image pairs: 2,3 then 3,4, then 4,5, etc.

Note: watch the signs on the pixel shifts in step 2.  The translation up/down and left/right depends on the order you process image frames (i.e. frame 2 - frame 1? or frame 1 - frame 2) and the orientation of the images(do pixel coordinates increase moving down or up?)